# How can I prove that the following are probability functions:

Tags: probability, functions

**a)** $f(x,y)=2^{-(x+y)}$

if $x,y = 1,2,…$ and  $f(x,y) = 0$ in any other case

**b)** $f(x,y)=16((1/3)^{(x+2y)})$

if $x,y = 1,2,…$ and  $f(x,y) = 0$ in any other case

Comment: Try summing the functions over all values of $x$ and $y$ and seeing if they equal 1.

Comment: For a) you have $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty} 2^{-y}\cdot \sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} 2^{-x}=...$ Can you proceed? Give a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove two conditions: i)$f(x,y)\geq0$ for all $(x,y)$, ii) $\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}}f(x,y)=1$ where $\mathbb{A}$ is the atom set.

a) It is an exponential function so $f(x,y)\geq0$ for all $(x,y)$. The serie is geometric:
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x+y}=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}\sum_{y=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y}=\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}=1$$

b) Again, it is an exponential so $f(x,y)\geq0$ for all $(x,y)$ and the serie is also geometric:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty 16\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x+2y}=16\sum_{x=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x}\sum_{y=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^{y}=16\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}\frac{1/9}{1-1/9}=16\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{8}=1$$